# Live agent in Sandbox ? Production?

Tags: sandbox, liveagent

I have set up live agent with pre chat form in sandbox, in the form action i have used https://xx.xxxx.salesforceliveagent.com/content/s/chat?language=en_US#deployment_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxKa&org_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&button_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&session_id=xxxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx

My doubt is if i dump the sandbox to production do i need to change the code of live agent? 
Will all these ID's changes again in production. Do i need to redo my work in production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about live agent, but as a rule you should **never** rely on IDs being the same in production as they are in sandbox. For starters, I can see you've got `org_id` in there, if that's not using a merge field you'll have issues (the same goes for `session_id`).

So though I'm not completely certain in this particular case, I think there's 99% change you're going to have to change these values when you move to production.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In live agent Salesforce itself will generate few javascript code for buttons and deployment of live agent. Isn't it a draw back with salesforce asking developers to redo everything in production ?

Comment: Sounds like a draw back if that's the case, but on the birght side it's only a small piece!